# Polymer not working on Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, polymer

I'm using Polymer in one of my web projects. In the index.html page, I included the script and include tags in the following way:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="styles/css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/mycss.css">
```

In the `body` tag, I'm using a `paper-button` the following way:

```
<paper-button class="blue-ripple" role="button" tabindex="0">Hello</paper-button>
```

It is rendering perfectly on Chrome (40.0.2214.111 m) but the ripple style is not working on Firefox (35.0.1). I've checked the console and there seem to be no conflicts or warnings or errors.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the polyfills:

```
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>
```

See https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/platform.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried adding webcomponents.min.js but it resulted in many console exception thrown in the browser.

Comment: Specifically, I get this error

`TypeError: this.each is not a function` on line 824 of `prototype.js`

The function block around that line goes

    `function o(e, t) {
        var n = [];
        this.each(function(r, i) { // line 824
            if (e.call(t, r, i)) n.push(r)
        });
        return n
    }`

Answer (score 0):

In the third `link` tag your `href` point to `styles/css`.
This could be the problem.

Comment: It renders some styles of the website. Uncommenting it didn't have any effect on the outcome though.